# function check if number is odd - not displaying anything

Tags: python

hi I have written a function to check if  number is odd but when I run my code nothing happens?

```
def is_odd(number):
    """check iff odd number """

    mod = number % 2

    if mod > 0:

        return True
    else:

        return False 

is_odd(2)
```

Comment: The function is returning `True` or `False`, not printing anything. Assign any variable to the function call with your parameters and it would be either `True` or `False`.

Comment: you never wrote anything that causes something to happen. the function is running just fine. What do you expect from it? (ps. think, print)

Comment: The funciton works and returns its result. You could shorten it to `return number%2 == 1` though and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You should print result to show something

```
print(is_odd(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print it, in order to see it. Something is actually happening :)

```
print(is_odd(2))
```